# Delphi Tokyo 10.2 - 710 invalid binary storage format

Tags: delphi, datasnap, firedac

I am working on firemonkey using REST/Jason, however, when I connect to my methods server through DataSnap Client Classes to get the return of my query, the following line throws an exception:

```
Result := TFDJSONDataSets(FUnMarshal.UnMarshal(FGetAlunoAutenticacaoCommand.Parameters[3].Value.GetJSONValue(True)));
```

[image]

Important:

It went without saying that the problem only occurs in the iOS simulator.

When I use ANDROID or WIN32 the problem does not happen.

[image]

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Consider using `TFDJSONDataSetsReader`, `TFDJSONDataSetsWriter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same error on iOS.
After some investigation, I found the bug causing this error in Embarcadero's source code.

Unit `Data.FireDACJSONReflect` has function `MemTableFromString(...)`. Inside this function the line (435) `LMemoryStream.Seek(Longint(0), soFromBeginning);` meant to set `LMemoryStream.Position` to `0`. It does so on all platforms except for iOS (I've tested on Win32/64 and Android). On iOS it does nothing. (the actual parameters of `Seek` function call becomes `0` and `soCurrent`).

Just changed this line (435) in unit `Data.FireDACJSONReflect`

```
LMemoryStream.Seek(Longint(0), soFromBeginning);
```

to the proper one

```
LMemoryStream.Seek(0, TSeekOrigin.soBeginning);
```

(You need to save corrected unit somewhere, add it to your project and replace old unit with the new one in `uses` clause of your source)